# SQL Pivot - Weather by Town Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am collecting weather data for a half dozen towns across 3 states.  The main things I am interested in is the temp and barometric pressure for this exercise.  What I am trying to do is turn a basic relational table into a report that looks something like:

| Date/Time | Firestone Temp | Firestone Pressure | Sedalia Temp | Sedalia Pressure | etc... | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-09 08:30:00 | 31.16 | 2019 | 40.65 | 2021 | etc... | etc... |
| 2021-11-09 09:00:00 | 31.16 | 2019 | 40.65 | 2021 | etc... | etc... |

The T-SQL tables (of importance) look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherResponse](
    [WeatherResponseId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Base] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Visibility] [int] NULL,
    [Dt] [int] NULL,
    [Timezone] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WeatherResponse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WeatherResponseId] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mains](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WeatherResponseId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Temp] [float] NOT NULL,
    [FeelsLike] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TempMin] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TempMax] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Pressure] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Humidity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SeaLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GrndLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Mains] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [WeatherResponseId] ASC
)
```

My pivot, however, is NOT producing the expected results.  Probably because I tripped over a rookie mistake as I work late at night on this!  ;)
*NOTE*:  I am working on just the TEMP at the moment but want both columns of data in the end.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Name]) 
                    from WeatherResponse
                    group by [Name]
                    order by ',' + QUOTENAME([Name])
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Created, Temp,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select r.Created, ((w.Temp-273.35) * (9/5)) + 32 as Temp, r.Name
                  from WeatherResponse r inner join Mains w on w.WeatherResponseId = r.WeatherResponseId
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Name)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

The results end up looking more like:

| Date/Time | Firestone Temp | Firestone Pressure | Sedalia Temp | Sedalia Pressure | etc... | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-09 08:30:00 | null | null | Sedalia | Sedalia | etc... | etc... |
| 2021-11-09 09:00:00 | null | null | Sedalia | Sedalia | etc... | etc... |
| 2021-11-09 08:30:00 | Firestone | Firestone | null | null | etc... | etc... |
| 2021-11-09 09:00:00 | Firestone | Firestone | null | null | etc... | etc... |

So, would someone slap me with that <DOH!/> moment please.  I need some caffeine.

EDIT:  Added photo of results in SQL Mangler...
[image: Image 01]

Comment: You cannot get any temperature or pressure with `max(name)`

Comment: True.  Using max(Temp) or max(Pressure) give this error:  Invalid column name 'Temp/Pressure'

Comment: Because `Temp` doesn't exist in the context of the *result* of `pivot`: it gets aggregated

Comment: @KeithBarrows In WeatherResponse, in the `Name` column, do you have `Firestone` or `Firestone Temp`? If you only have `Firestone` and you want a dynamic column composed by `WeatherResponse.Name + Main.ColumnName` you should do a cross join with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, don't you?

Comment: I mean something like  `select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Name]+' '+c.COLUMN_NAME) 
                    from WeatherResponse w cross join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
                    where c.TABLE_NAME = N'Mains'
                    group by [Name], c.COLUMN_NAME
                    order by ',' + QUOTENAME([Name]+' '+c.COLUMN_NAME)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')`

Comment: SQL Server only allows you pivot one set of results at a time, that's why you're seeing the alternating `null` values. i.e.: you'd need to pivot `Pressure` data and `Temp` data separately then join the two result sets on the common key, which is probably your `Created` values.

Comment: @Carlos - thanks.  Was not as worried about that right now.  I cannot get Temp *OR* Pressure values in a single row of data - yet.  That is more important to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already was said, T-SQL doesn't support `pivot` with multiple aggregate functions, so you may use conditional aggregation for the same functionality. As long as you generate the code and you do not need to type it manually, one possible drawback may be the size of resulting query.

> ```
> DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
>     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
>
> ;select @cols = STUFF((
>   SELECT DISTINCT
>     replace(replace(replace(
>       ', max(iif([Name]=val, [Temp], null)) as coltemp, max(iif([Name] = val, [Pressure], null)) as colpres
> '
>       /*Substitute quoted value string*/
>       , 'val', quotename([Name], '''')
>       )
>       /*Substitute temperature column name*/
>       , 'coltemp', QUOTENAME([Name] + ' temp')
>       )
>       /*Substitute pressure column name*/
>       , 'colpres', quotename([Name] + ' pressure')
>       )
>   from WeatherResponse
>   group by [Name]
>   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
> ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,1,'')
>
> ;set @query = '
> SELECT Created
> ,' + @cols + '
> from (
>   select
>     r.Created
>     , ((w.Temp-273.35) * (9/5)) + 32 as Temp
>     , pressure
>     , r.Name
>   from WeatherResponse r
>     inner join Mains w
>       on w.WeatherResponseId = r.WeatherResponseId
> ) as x
> group by created'
>
> ;execute( @query)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Created                     | Firestone temp | Firestone pressure | Sedalia temp | Sedalia pressure
> :-------------------------- | -------------: | -----------------: | -----------: | ---------------:
> 2021-11-16 17:12:48.1233333 |        -231.35 |                100 |      -221.35 |              300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7aa9dea4c9ef1f436398b475e536feeb)*

What about your original issue: as I said, `[Temp]` column is not available in the result set, it is aggregated by `pivot`.

And a side note: please, do not include so much unused columns with `not null` in the table definition when you prepare minimal reproducible example. They doesn't help to insert some sample data, which is essential for dynamic query.

Comment: This works.  I am still not quite grokking the entire piece but I am closer to enlightenment so thank you!